# Text over multiple lines flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to include a list of all the third party libraries I've used and thinking of just pasting all the licences into a string but I can't have a string over multiple lines in flutter.

```
  String licences = 'asfasdf
  asdf';
```

The above is an example and this shows an error: Expected to find ';'.dart(expected_token)
Unterminated string literal.dart(unterminated_string_literal)

How can I achieve this so I can paste all the licences into a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use triple quote for multiple lines

```
String licences = '''asfasdf
                     asdf''';
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/String-class.html